# Float: right on responsive site

Tags: css, css-float

I'm having so difficulty making a my social div float right. I noticed when I add float:right the size of the body size changes which is why it is moving the div down a bit but without the float:right the body size is correct. how can I fix this?

[Website](http://www.tamarinarestaurants.com)

Here's my code:

```
    #social{
      width:102px;
      height:34px;
      padding-left:1%;
      padding-top:1%;
    }
    body{
      background-image: url('images/bg-2.jpg');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position:bottom;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
      max-width: 100%;
      overflow-x:hidden;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't even need to use `float: right`, please use the CSS below and this should work perfectly:

```
#social {
     width: 100%;
     height: 34px;
     padding-right: 1%;
     padding-left: 0%;
     padding-top: 1%;
     text-align: right;
}

#icons {
     padding-right: 0.5%;
}
```

Comment: it is also great to go with this, i recommend this

Answer (score 0):

actually problem is with your margins, just adjust the margins on #block element than problem will be solved
for instance turn off the margin from #block(both left margin and top margin) and apply float:right to #social and see.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is because of `margin-top:15%` on your `#block`.

add `position: absolute;` to your `#block` style, and then `float:right` your `#social`

that fixed the issue.....